# Cross sheet trace dependents not working when using IF TODAY formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here's how to reproduce the issue:

Put the following formula in Sheet1, cell A1:

```
=IF(TODAY()>0,Sheet2!A1,A2)
```

Trace precedents works fine, trace dependends from A2 also works. However the cell Sheet2!A1 says it has no dependents.

I've tried:

- Different Excel versions (2010, 2013)
- Rebuilding dependency tree

Neither of those worked. This was an issue in a big Excel file with massive nested IFs, however it can be reduced to the example above.

Comment: `TODAY()>0` is always going to evaluate to `TRUE` because every day is greater than zero... What exactly are you trying to do? Can you provide some dummy data?

Comment: I know it's always `TRUE`, it doesn't matter. I just wanted to provide the simplest possible example to reproduce the issue. I will be comparing `TODAY()` vs a date in some other cell.

Comment: I can confirm the same behavior with 2016.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't need to be within an if statement  `=today()+sheet2!A1` does the same thing.  Definitely say its a bug.

Comment: This is just a problem excel has. It doesn't work in VBA either - nothing to do with your `if`